# SwiftUI: ProgressView inside Button on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have a "Sign In" button which calls an API asynchronously. I'd like to show a spinner until the response from the server arrives.

The code for this button looks like this:

```
Button(action: signIn) {
    if isSigningIn {
        ProgressView()
            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: .white))
    } else {
        Text(I18n.signInButton)
    }
}
.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
```

The above has several issues though:

- The spinner is too large and is shown outside the button (I could probably address this using a .frame modifier)
- The spinner should be white because of the prominent blue button, but despite having tint set to white it still appears black.

Is there a proper solution for macOS or is it conceptually wrong to have a spinner in a button for this platform?

Comment: Maybe opinionated but I would find it a bit confusing and not typical for a Mac app to have a spinner inside a button.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Where would you show the spinner instead? Overlapped to the username/password text fields?

Comment: Some kind of sheet centred in the current window or perhaps somewhere directly in the window if there is some place that fits the layout.

Comment: for the size, you could use `.scaleEffect(0.5, anchor: .top)`

Comment: Try to apply `.controlSize(.small)` to progressview